# Delay boot completed android, (30 seconds)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bootcompleted

I would like to delay process when device boot complete...

Fo example... when boot complete, the activity start after 30 seconds..

there is a code to put in the Manifest ? or a solution without using to the Timer or similar function ?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a timer or other similar function? Personally, I'd have a broadcast receiver that listens for boot complete intent, sleeps for 30 seconds, and then does some action.

Incidentally, do you necessarily know that the user WANTS your app to automatically start when the device starts? Personally, I'd find it infuriating if an app did that; I don't recommend this unless the device is specifically dedicated to running your app (e.g. if you're running an app on a tablet in Kiosk mode).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a timer.

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask;
```

in your `onReceive` method

```
timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, DELAY, PERIOD);
```

DELAY: milliseconds before starts.

PERIOD: milliseconds to repeat, you can stop for avoid repeat.

The method:

```
public void initializeTimerTask() {
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //your code
        }
    };
}
```

then you can stop it

```
if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
```